# Search in a string and create an array in PHP

Tags: php, string, search

How to convert this string

```
 *|text:student:required|*
```

( * and | is part of string ) into array like this

```
['text' ,'student','required']
```

Comment: `|` is part of the string?

Comment: yes *| is part of string, string format is *|text:student:required|*

Comment: ok @Rehman, Check out the answer.

Comment: @RehmanAkbar so, did any solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks @mega6382 your solution works.

Comment: @RehmanAkbar Than please be sure to accept it.

Comment: @mega6382 can you please guide me how to remove p tag if string is like this <p>*|text:student:required|*</p>

Comment: @RehmanAkbar Sure, try `$str = strip_tags($str);`

Comment: Thanks again @mega6382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
$str = '*|text:student:required|*';
$str = preg_replace("/[|*]/", '', $str);
$arr = explode(':', $str);
```

this simply removes the `|` AND `*` from the string using `preg_replace()` and the turns the string into an array using `explode`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$str = "|text:student:required|";
$str = trim($str,"|");
$str = trim($str,"*");
$x = explode(':',$str);
print_r($x);die;
```

Comment: Your solution is invalid. The `*` is before and after `|` not vice versa.

Comment: @mega6382, that was his typo. Please check the updated post.

Comment: Yes, but you are trimming `|` before `*` you should `trim` `|` after `*`. you should shift your lines 2 and 3.

Comment: You're using a simpler initial string. Also you can use `trim($str, "|*")` to trim either of those from either end without needing to worry about order

Answer (score 1):

The shortest one with [**preg_split**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function:

```
$s = '*|text:student:required|* ';
$result = preg_split('/[*:| ]+/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => student
    [2] => required
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "*|text:student:required|";
$string = str_replace("*", "", str_replace("|","", $string));
$array = explode(':', $string);
```

Comment: actually there is a * and | sign at the start and end of string